# Why is my form submission in deployment breaking (React+Firestore)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This works fine in development, but when I deploy many of my functions break. E.g., I have a form that adds data to the database but when I submit it, it just refreshes the page but the data never makes it to the database.

```
onSubmit = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        const { phoneNumber, points } = this.state;
        let pointsToAdd = Number(points);
        if(user) {
            const docRef = database.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('customers').doc(phoneNumber);
            docRef.set({
                points: pointsToAdd
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('success');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
            window.location.href = '/';
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's refreshing, then the user variable is null. So, you must not be signed in on your deployed version. Just add a firebase signin function first before calling that one!

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not logged in on the non-dev environment, the current implementation will simply redirect when no user is found.

As feedback on your current submit-handler: I think you want to listen to `authStateChanged` when your components mounts instead of when the submit handler is called. Update the state accordingly and use the user from the state when reaching for the correct document.

For example:

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) this.setState({ user })
    else window.location.href = '/'
  })
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  this.unsubscribe() // don't forget to unsubscribe when unmounting!
}

onSubmit = () => {
  const { phoneNumber, points, user } = this.state;
  let pointsToAdd = Number(points);

  database.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('customers').doc(phoneNumber)
    .set({
      points: pointsToAdd
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('success');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try in a bit.